# Get 3 divs with margin in one line

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to get 3 divs next to each other. 
They need to fill out the space of 980px, but the div left and right may not have an margin on the outside.

How do i fix this?

Comment: How big are the margins that **are** allowed...cos it matters.

Comment: i got 3 divs with 310px width, and only the second div need to have 25px left and 25px right margin.

Comment: You are slowly feeding us more details about what you are trying to do. PLEASE take time to write out some more details and post some HTML.

Comment: @user3652488: Here's a solution to use if you have 6, 9, or more divs in the container.  The only difference from the solution that I've submitted is using `:nth-of-type` selector with the "formula".  Other than that, the approach is exactly the same: http://jsfiddle.net/JQD3U/.  Cheers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a solution that does not use margins: http://jsfiddle.net/c33eM/.

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 980px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}

.container > div {
    width: 310px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container > div:first-of-type {
    float: left;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container > div:last-of-type {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Except that this only works with 3 internal divs...add three more (as the OP commented) and it breaks.

Comment: The question specified a container of 980px and in the comments to the question it mentions three internal divs of 310px each.  That's the requirements I worked with.  If the OP wants to add more divs, then it is easily addressed just by using nth-of-type selector and using the "formula".  Here you go, genius: http://jsfiddle.net/JQD3U/.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:first-child` and `:last-child` to set the margins to zero.

Assuming your columns have the class `column`, you can use the following CSS code

```
.column:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
.column:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8GLT/)

Comment: I see, but i fetch the data from my database. So i'll get like 30 divs, 10 rows with 3 divs next to each other..

Comment: Put every 3 divs into a separate row container. Rows should be on top of each other and occupy 100% of the width.

Answer (score -1):

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9T2ss/2/)**

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:980px;
    background-color: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
    width:310px;
    margin-right:25px;
    float:left;
    height:75px;
    background-color: #663399;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container div:nth-child(3n) { 
   /* removes margin-right from every 3rd div */
    margin-right:0;
}
```